# return sqlite3_column_text() to literal string

Tags: c, string, pointers, sqlite, literals

I have the following doubt:

Consider a SELECT to the following table from an sqlite database:

```
id | label
1  | P1
1  | P2
1  | P3
1  | P4
```

I run the following test code:

```
const unsigned char * new1;
const unsigned char * new2;
const unsigned char * new3;
const unsigned char * new4;

sqlite3_step(stmt);
new1=sqlite3_column_text(stmt,1);

sqlite3_step(stmt);
new2=sqlite3_column_text(stmt,1);

sqlite3_step(stmt);
new3=sqlite3_column_text(stmt,1);

sqlite3_step(stmt);
new4=sqlite3_column_text(stmt,1);

printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",new1,new2,new3,new4);
printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n",new1,new2,new3,new4);
```

And I get:

```
P4
P4
P4
P4
0x1d5b7f8
0x1d5b7f8
0x1d5b7f8
0x1d5b7f8
```

I want to print

```
P1
P2
P3
P4
Address1
Address2
Address3
Address4
```

Is there any way to print this with only string literal without using buffer const char value[N];, strcpy, etc ...?

Answer (score 5):

> The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called. The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically.

Unless you `printf` after each `sqlite3_column_text` (address will still be the same even then), you'll need to make copies.